# What is the efficient Json format to send table column update data

Tags: json, database

I have to create a service that can create a json data to update changes to a table. The format I initially thought was:

```
"tables" : [{
    "tableName" : JSONString,
    "row" : [{
        "rowId" : JSONString,
        "columnItems" : [{
            "columnName"    : JSONString
            "columnValue"      : JSONString
        }] 
    }]
}]
```

But there will be millions of rows so the json will be too big. So I have to make sure that I use this data efficiently.

So, I thought I can use a structure like this:

```
"tables" : [{
    "tableName" : JSONString,
    "row" : [{
        "rowId" : JSONString,
        "columnItems" : [{
            "columnValue"      : JSONString
        }] 
    }]
}]
```

With above template I removed the columnName. but I can't use it as not all columns will be updated. I need to carry the columnName some how.

Wondering if there is a better template to convey this data.

Comment: can you assume that all rows always have the same columns ? If you cannot, you could provide a pair of Index-Value for each column, instead of providing the name (can save you some bytes, perhaps some Kbytes ?)

Comment: yes. I can assume that

Comment: if you can, why then you need to send the column names ? You certainly need not under every row object.

Comment: I have no actual experience with this, but perhaps using a Hash function to codify a given row and all its values into some sort of unique key where the receiver of the json could recode it back to the original values - thus saving bytes in the json size as well ?

Comment: I like your idea. I will try it out and see

Comment: More practically, you could have a dictionary where the key is a guid object (which is unique) and the data associated with it is a list of strings / or a list of key value pairs, where the key is the column index and the value is the column/field value. The question is if this makes sense in your scenario... I mean, the json sender will send it this way - but only if you have control over receiver then you may be fine in decoding the info back. And you should define this dectionary only once and have it shared between sender and receiver.

Comment: What is the purpose of guid object? I am thinking that one of the column value is rowID and when hash( entire row) get decrypted then I can keep track with the help of rowID.

Comment: Guid is just an object that knows how to generate a uniquely identifiable string. If your RowId is also uniquely identifiable, same thing.

Comment: I am reading online about Hash function and noticed that decoding an encrypted string using hash function may not always return same string back. Do you have any idea about that?